# MongoDB: tag-aware sharding as a way to pre-split data

Tags: mongodb, split, sharding, chunks

We have a job-processing system in which workers will bulk insert hundreds of thousands of documents in our mongodb in parallel. Each worker will insert the data batches, each batch will belong to the same group_id. I've setup 3 shards for our database and I would like to pre-split those group_ids in round robin fashion. For example:

> group_id: 1 --> shard1
>
> group_id: 2 --> shard2
>
> group_id: 3 --> shard3
>
> group_id: 4 --> shard1
>
> group_id: 5 --> shard2
>
> ... etc

The idea is to increase write throughput, the workers will process groups incrementally, and so with this pre-splitting, in theory 3 workers should be able to bulk insert in parallel without waiting on each other (we have a local mongos server on each worker).

I have implemented the idea above using tagged sharding sh.addTagRange() command. But the chunks are not split correctly? Everything is ending up in the primary shard, this defeats the whole purpose of pre-splitting the data. If tag-aware sharding is not the proper method to implement this round-robin distribution of key values, then how would someone pre-split the data in that manner? I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you try splitting your chunks at the tag boundaries using sh.splitAt()?

Comment: this might be a better question for Google group mongodb-user

Comment: Thanks guys. @JamesWahlin, I've tried splitAt before and it did not rotate the chunks as I was looking to have. However, when used in conjunction with tags it seems to work very well! The downside is that it is EXTREMELY slow. I'm thinking now of directly inserting into the "config.chunks" collection but I'm not sure how wise that would be? Keep in mind that I will do this before loading any data at all.

Comment: I would avoid any manual editing of "config.chunks". A better route would be exploration into why the split is slow. I agree with Asya that this would be better explored under the mongodb-user Google group.